# How to efficiently manage source control between source code and obfuscated javascript?

Tags: javascript, git, heroku

I am building an app in javascript and so I have a git repository where I store my source code. I am deploying this app on an heroku server (there is a static node.js backend), and I also do this through git. When I push to heroku though, I am pushing an obfuscated (uglified) version of my code, so that the code is not easily copyable. I made a Makefile that allows me to script the uglification of my code, and I have my html test file that points to this. For development though, I have to switch back my test page to point to the source code. I am looking for the simplest solution to handle my source code and my production release in an efficient way. What are the various solutions to handle this? 2 git repository? One for source code, and one for the release? with a script that creates one from the other? Or is there a easier way to manage this?

Answer (score 1):

You keep only one source repository with your source code in clear human readable, developer friendly format. Your build process should take a build profile as input. Build profile value will decide whether your build will uglify/minify needed resources or not. If build profile is 'production' your build script will uglify/minify the needed resources. In 'development' profile you deploy the resources as-is so that you can debug the code easily.

Comment: Ravih, thanks for your answer. I guess my question is where does the output of the build go to? Another git repository that is associated with heroku? Or the same repository in a specific folder?

Comment: Build output is a generated output. Build output does not go to any repository. You build a specific version of your source code, deploy it wherever you want to deploy it. That's all.

Comment: yes, I guess that's right. I was confused because to deploy to heroku, you need to push the build through git. I'll make another repo just to do that then...

Comment: Oh, yes. You can do that. It will be a scratch repository used just for the purpose of pushing the build.